# Differences in mysql version when passing version attribute

Tags: mysql, macos-sierra

Why does the following happen?

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

$ mysql -v
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Are there two versions of mysql? How do I get rid of the one that isnt mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing `--version` and `-v`.  From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/command-line-options.html):

> Option names are case sensitive. **-v and -V** are both legal and have different meanings. (They are the corresponding short forms of the **--verbose and --version** options.)

I think that when you typed `mysql -v` you tried to start MySQL with some sort of verbose flag turned on.  Regardless, you did not specify a username or password.  So it tried to use your Linux username with no password, which failed.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning, too, is that neither of these, used with `mysql`, is the version of the MySQL Server... it's the client version, which can differ.